# How can do I multiple filtering in Express JS and Mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, next.js

I have created a Real Estate Website with NextJS, ExpressJS  and Mongodb, its almost completed, but One thing I still can't figure out is to how I can apply multiple filtering as per I created In frontend.[image: Filter 1][image: Filter 2]

I want to know how can I created an API where I can fetch data according multiple applied filter

I have already created an API where I have implemented Pagination feature but still confused how can I create something like this

Comment: how does your query looks, and what is the payload structure with filters

Comment: amenities section store value in array, and other option has there individual storing space i.e if we select pets value not allowed than the value will look like {pets:"notallowed"} and in amenity {amenity:["lift"]}